# Where do use the ./configure to set python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

I am trying to fix a problem with zlib and python, and I need to run the following command, but I can't figure out where:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/Python-2.7.8 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: The same place you used it originally.

Comment: I get "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then you're not in the same place you used it originally.

Answer (score 0):

the `./configure` script is used to configure the build for your system. Usually you would download a tarball and unpack it in some directory, then run the configure script, `make` and finally `make install` which will install the code in the location you provided in the `./configure` step.

You want to look for this script in the source directory, that is where ever the python source code you built from is